# Popup Menu anchor with large EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a large EditText that covers the whole screen. The text inside the EditText is made clickable using ClickableSpan. When user clicks on the ClickableSpan, a popup menu is displayed giving option to choose from.

The problem is, if the large EditText is made the anchor, there is no space above or below the EditText to display the Popup menu. The only solution I could come up with is create empty TextView and put it inside the EditText and then use that as anchor. Is that the best I can do or are there better ways?

Comment: use `PopupWindow#showAtLocation` then

Comment: Do I have I have to use popup window instead of popup menu?

Comment: ooops,  sorry i overlooked  you are using popup menu...

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: Is it possible to get the position of click (x,y position) when the clickablespan is clicked?

Comment: not exactly click position, but you can get span coordinates, via `Layout` class (`TextView.getLayout()`)